# Getting an external webapi url given a list of routes it uses

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, url-routing

I have a WebAPI (v1) app that I'm creating. It has various custom routes, that all work fine.

I have a client application I'm creating (which is MVC+webapi itself), which calls the webapi app using `HttpClient`. Currently I've hard-coded the urls to call, but I'd like to calculate them automatically based on a list of routes (which I could put in a shared library).

So, in my shared library I would have a list of a class that contains `Name`, `RouteTemplate` and `Defaults`, which in my webapi I'd iterate through that list to create my routes and in the client application i'd somehow use to calculate the url to get `HttpClient` to call.

How do I calculate the url to call an external webapi app from a client app (that could itself have its own routing)?

Comment: What do you mean with calculate? You have the table with all the routes, so you can register them in the api. At the client side, you also should know the parameters you need to fill. Do you mean that with calculating?

Comment: At the client side I know the paramters to fill, and the action/method I want to call but, given the paramters to fill and the route name I want to use, how do I get the url to GET/POST to?

Comment: Well you can filter the routes table on action / controller in that case. Besides that you should also define in that routes table that it should have a get, post, put verb and filter on that too if you have 2 actions with the same name in the same controller. 

if the route contains placeholders you can replace them with the parameter name. You put the rest of the parameters  in the body of the request

Comment: Note that the routes table in the client app is different to the webapi app I want to call (but I do have data to create the routes of the webapi app). Does this change things? How would I get the actual url, with parameter names filled in automatically using the webapi app's list of routes (not the calling app's)?

Answer (score 0):

So since I know what you want, I give it a try

So I assume you have a routes table for your api which has the colums: route, controller, action, verb. An example row could be:

> /foo/bar/{id}, fooController, barAction, GET

In the client app you have access to that data so you can compose an url of that when you know which controller and action to call with which verb. The combination of controller, action and verb is unique in mvc.

So you filter on fooController , barAction and verb GET and you get the route. You replace {id} with your id parameter and you have an url.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have a more complex route, like `/Customers/{custid}/Branches/{branchid}/Orders/{id}` (with the last id being `RouteParameter.Optional`)? I don't want to have to re-create the logic that MVC/WebAPI does when routing. I was hoping to leverage framework classes somehow.

Comment: Im not sure how you have your parameter data present, so I can't give you a clear and complete answer to that. You can have look at the source code of ActionUrl method which you use in mvc to get the same result. Im not sure the is any native mvc/asp.net code which does what you want